# What does "いんやぁ" mean?

Tags: meaning, colloquial-language, interjections

I've tried scouring through various Japanese dictionaries with no luck.

For some context:
Person A has just heard person B and C have gotten married:

> いんやぁ~おめでたいよねぇ~！

Answer (score 7):

Judging from the context you provided, 「いんやぁ」 would have to be the informal pronunciation of 「いやあ」, which is an exclamation of surprise.

「ん」 quite often appears in a similar fashion for emphasis in colloquial speech.

「すんごい」 for 「すごい」,

「うんめえ」 for 「うめえ」, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a dialect called 尾道弁,　which is being widely used by people who live around 尾道市（広島県南東部）.

```
いんやぁ   嫌だ。(例1.いんやぁ、しとうないわぁ)/ 
          言いなさい。(例2.あの人に、いんやぁ)
```

Resource quoted:
https://bisan.co.jp/%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%8C%E5%B0%BE%E9%81%93%E5%BC%81%E3%81%98%E3%82%83-p-onoken005/ *(これが尾道弁じゃ)*

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B0%BE%E9%81%93%E5%B8%82 (WikiPedia尾道市)

Comment: If so, then why doesn't the 「おめでたいよねぇ~」 part sound like 尾道弁 at all?  That sounds completely standard.

Comment: Because 嫌だ could mean something more than unpleasant. For two middle-aged Japanese women, when they talk in their daily life you would heard 嫌だ a lot. It's just like ''oh my god'' in English. So I would assume when A heard that B and C got married, he/she says いやんぁ only in order to express the surprise.

Comment: Well, I was just saying there could be one possibility.

Comment: I've noticed that whenever the possibility of a regional dialect comes up, it tends to get downvoted regardless of whether it's a plausible answer or not. I wouldn't worry about it, it's still relevant and useful information and people will benefit from the knowledge.